# Putting Activity Indicator near a check box

Tags: blackberry, java-me, activity-indicator

I have some checkboxes which are selected to determine what kind of checks will be performed. The checks are started using a start button. What I want is when I press the start button I want an actiuvity indicator next to the check box that is selected to perform a check.

I read the [Activity Indicator](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/18125/Activity_indicator_1214556_11.jsp) documentation but I am not sure how to achieve what I want based on that information. Any ideas ?

Comment: "I want an actiuvity indicator next to the check box that is selected to perform a check"....My question is , Do you need a Loader(loading while performing checks )..something like this

Comment: Place an indicator near each check and show/hide them as needed.

Comment: How do I link them to each process though ?